# First attempt at docker compose, status is "restarting" what have I done wrong?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

This is my first attempt at docker composer (and docker since yesterday), however the docker is in a restarting state.

The application is Grafana which I normally run with:

```
docker volume create grafana-storage
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana grafana/grafana
```

Today I thought I'd try using docker composer, here is what I have done:Create a folder for the Docker App(s)

```
sudo mkdir Docker_Applications
cd Docker_Applications
sudo mkdir Grafana
```

Go into the directory

```
cd Grafana
sudo nano docker-compose.yml
```

add

```
version: '3'
services:
 grafana:
   image: "grafana/grafana:7.3.7"
   volumes:
     # Data persistency
     # sudo mkdir -p /Docker_Applications/Grafana
     - "./database:/var/lib/grafana"
     - "./config:/etc/grafana"
   ports:
     - 3000:3000
   restart: always
```

Then ran it

```
root@grafana-dev:/Docker_Applications/Grafana$ sudo docker-compose up -d
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Starting grafana_grafana_1 ... done
```

status

```
root@grafana-dev:/Docker_Applications/Grafana$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND     CREATED          STATUS                         PORTS     NAMES
a347b12ae9a3   grafana/grafana:7.3.7   "/run.sh"   18 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 4 seconds ago             grafana_grafana_1
```

Hopefully you can see I've tried my best. I wonder if it's to do with the volumes.

Any help would be really appreciated.

I removed the volumes section of the yaml file and it runs now.  It looks like permissions or it can't locate my folders, i'm not sure what permissions/commands to try.

```
grafana-dev:/Docker_Applications/Grafana$ sudo docker-compose up
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Creating grafana_grafana_1 ... done
Attaching to grafana_grafana_1
grafana_1  | mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied
grafana_1  | GF_PATHS_CONFIG='/etc/grafana/grafana.ini' is not readable.
grafana_1  | GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.
grafana_1  | You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migration-from-a-previous-version-of-the-docker-container-to-5-1-or-later
```

Comment: What do the container logs show? (e.g., `docker-compose logs grafana`)

Comment: In your original `docker run` setup you were using a named volume; your Compose setup uses a bind-mounted host directory.  Does switching to a named volume in the Compose case help?

Comment: have you seen this documentation, the last section talks about user permission for files and volumes. I think it might solve your issue [Grafana Docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#migration-from-a-previous-version-of-the-docker-container-to-5-1-or-later)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the container exits during startup due to an error and since you've set `restart: always` in your docker-compose file, the container automatically restarts.

Check the logs or just run `docker-compose up` non-detached by removing the `-d` flag to find out what the problem is, fix that and your container will stop restarting itself continuously.

Comment: Hello, I just updated my post at the top (bottom section), seems removing the volumes section helps, logs say it's permissions?

Comment: @AndyWhite When you're mounting a folder that's on your host, you have to deal with the permissions of that folder. Grafana is probably running with a user that does not have sufficient rights for the folder on the host system. The [Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/) say Grafana runs under the "grafana" user, can you do a `ls -la` from inside the folder than contains the docker-compose file to see what the permissions on the mounted folders are?